# Generate automatic SQL reports and output them to Google sheets

Tags: sql, google-sheets

Currently, I'm running several reports using SQL copying the data to Google sheets, amending said data to generate daily stats.
Most of the reports I run using SQL have the same date range.
If it helps I can post a couple of the SQL reports.
I'm hoping there's a way to automate this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: We use a custom DBMS. I run queries on a live database using Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Apps Script to pull data from SQL to Google Sheets and you can automate it by adding a time-driven trigger to run depending on how frequent you want it to.

### References

[Installable Trigger(Apps Script)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

[How to Retrieve SQL Data Automatically Using Google Sheets Script](https://www.actiondesk.io/blog/google-sheets-script-to-automatically-retrieve-sql-data)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We have connected Google Apps Script to pull data. I want to now run a long query, do you know how  I would implement this?

Comment: What do you mean by "long query"? Have you encountered problems/errors when trying to perform the query via Apps Script?

Comment: @DavidBill7 did my answer helped you in your concern/question? Feel free to upvote/accept the answer if that's the case so other members of the community can see it.